# XSL: Output missing when path is provided as parameter

Tags: xslt-1.0

I try to understand why in my code produces a different result when I change the definition to use parameters with the same value, as I would like to call a template from other locations in the xls providing the path as a parameter so the code is reusable rather than tailored to the location in the XML

```
    <!--  Create SLA bar section  -->
    <xsl:template name="createBars">
       <xsl:param name="varPath"/>  <!-- Not used -->
       <xsl:param name="varNode"/>  <!-- Not used -->
       <table id="tblgraph" align="center" width="100" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
         <tr style='width:100%'>
           <td align="left" width="100%" height="10" colspan="12">
             <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" width="100%" style='color:black; font-weight:bold;'>
               <xsl:for-each select="/page/workgroups/workgroup/queue/currentshift/servicelevels">
                   <xsl:for-each select="servicelevel">
                     <xsl:variable name="keyValue">
                       <xsl:value-of select="key"/>
                     </xsl:variable>
                     <xsl:variable name="valueContent">
                       <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
                     </xsl:variable>                       
                     <tr>
                       <td>
                         <xsl:value-of select="$keyValue"/>
                       </td>
                       <td>
                         <xsl:value-of select="$valueContent"/>..
                       </td>
                     </tr>
                  </xsl:for-each>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </xsl:template>
```

Which create the expected output of a table

```
 0..20 | -..
20..30 | -..
30..40 | -..
40..50 | -..
50..60 | -..
60..70 | -..
70+    | -..
```

However when I change the code to use the passed parameters that have been set in the calling part of the template , replacing

```
 <xsl:for-each select="/page/workgroups/workgroup/queue/currentshift/servicelevels">
```

with

```
 <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($varPath)">
```

and

```
 <xsl:for-each select="servicelevel">
```

with

```
 <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($varNode)">
```

the result is empty

Result:

```
 ..
```

In the calling profile the parameter is set like this:

```
  <!-- Set path and node for the information to be processed to build the bars -->
  <xsl:variable name="tempPath">
    <xsl:copy-of select="/page/workgroups/workgroup/queue/currentshift/servicelevels"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="tempNode">
    <xsl:copy-of select="servicelevel"/>
  </xsl:variable>
            
  <!-- Call the template to build the bars -->
  <xsl:call-template name="createBars">
    <xsl:with-param name="varPath" select="$tempPath"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="varNode" select="$tempNode"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
```

How can I specify a parameter representing a path like:
`/page/workgroups/workgroup/queue/currentshift/servicelevels` and `servicelevel` 
which can be modified to for example:
`/page/workgroups/workgroup/queue/currentperiod/abandoneds` and `abandoned`

This all to be able to recall the template to create bar values based on similar entries in the statistical information.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page id="7080959">
  <name>Test Ruud</name>
  <description/>
  <server>reg6699cic01</server>
  <created>2014/07/25 08:12:01 AM</created>
  <workgroups>
    <workgroup>
      <name>ITSD_APAC_Windows_Manila</name>
        <agents>2</agents>
          <queue>
           <longesttalktime>-</longesttalktime>
           <longestwaiting>-</longestwaiting>
           <currentperiod>
             <numberabandoned>0</numberabandoned>
             <periodlength>00:11:59</periodlength>
             <servicelevels>
               <servicelevel>
                 <key>0..20</key>
                 <value>98</value>
               </servicelevel>
               <servicelevel>
                 <key>20..30</key>
                 <value>100</value>
               </servicelevel>
             </servicelevels>
             <abandoneds>
               <abandoned>
                 <key>0..20</key>
                 <value>-</value>
               </abandoned>
               <abandoned>
                 <key>20..30</key>
                 <value>-</value>
               </abandoned>
             </abandoneds>
           </currentperiod>
           <currentshift>
             <numberabandoned>4</numberabandoned>
             <periodlength>21:11:59</periodlength>
             <servicelevels>
               <servicelevel>
                 <key>0..20</key>
                 <value>-</value>
               </servicelevel>
               <servicelevel>
                 <key>20..30</key>
                 <value>-</value>
               </servicelevel>
             </servicelevels>
             <abandoneds>
               <abandoned>
                 <key>0..20</key>
                 <value>1</value>
             </abandoned>
             <abandoned>
               <key>20..30</key>
               <value>-</value>
             </abandoned>
           </abandoneds>
         </currentshift>
       </queue>
     </workgroup>
   </workgroups>
 </page>
```

So targets for the bar template would be:

- `/page/workgroups/workgroup/queue/currentshift/servicelevels` with six sub nodes for `ServiceLevel`
- `/page/workgroups/workgroup/queue/currentshift/abandoneds` with six sub nodes for `abandoned`
- `/page/workgroups/workgroup/queue/currentperiod/servicelevel` with six sub nodes for `servicelevel`
- `/page/workgroups/workgroup/queue/currentperiod/abandoneds` with six sub nodes for `abandoned`

  each of these nods contain
- `Key`
- `Value`

Looking forward to your replies

Comment: Could you minimize your example to only what's necessary to show the problem? It seems you are trying to use a *string* parameter as the select XPath expression. That's not going to work.

Comment: so how do I do this then?

Comment: I would gladly tell you if I could only understand the problem. Minimize, please.

Comment: You are providing a lot of information, but there's lots of things that do not really matter for your question. Try to break it down by leaving away stuff - but make sure your problem is still present.

Comment: I've modified the question, is this more appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

First, my assumption why you are obtaining an empty result set: Your concrete problem arises from the fact that you pass an empty node set to the second parameter of your template:

```
<xsl:variable name="tempNode">
  <xsl:copy-of select="servicelevel"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

At the time the XSLT processor evaluates this expression it tries to find all `<servicelevel>` children of the **current node**. Most likely, there are none since the fact that you use the full path for your first parameter

```
<xsl:variable name="tempPath">
  <xsl:copy-of select="/page/workgroups/workgroup/queue/currentshift/servicelevels"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

shows us that the context in which you define the variable is probably *not* `/page/workgroups/workgroup/queue/currentshift/servicelevels`.

Now for a fix: Judging from your XSLT you try to define a base node set located in `tempPath` and then loop over the children of these node given by the relative path provided in `tempNode`. As @michael.hor257k already pointed out this does not work in XSLT (at least not 1.0 or 2.0) although you actually did not pass a string but an empty node.

In your particular case, however, you might be able to simplify your template by eliminating the inner loop. This should be possible since there is no functionality in your outer loop that is not also in the inner loop. So instead of calling the template with two parameters just use one parameter containing all nodes of the inner loop:

```
<xsl:variable name="tempNode">
  <xsl:copy-of select="/page/workgroups/workgroup/queue/currentshift/servicelevels/servicelevel"/>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- Call the template to build the bars -->
<xsl:call-template name="createBars">
  <xsl:with-param name="varNode" select="$tempNode"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

You simplify your template as follows:

```
<!--  Create SLA bar section  -->
<xsl:template name="createBars">
   <xsl:param name="varNode"/> 
   <table id="tblgraph" align="center" width="100" 
          cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
     <tr style='width:100%'>
       <td align="left" width="100%" height="10" colspan="12">
         <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" 
                width="100%" style='color:black; font-weight:bold;'>
           <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($varNode)">

           ... add here the contents of the !inner! loop

           </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</xsl:template>
```

This way you eliminate the need for evaluating a relative path!

**Complete Solution**

The following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:common="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:variable name="tempPath">
      <xsl:copy-of select="/page/workgroups/workgroup/queue/currentshift/servicelevels/servicelevel"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <tables>
      <xsl:call-template name="createBars">
        <xsl:with-param name="varNode" select="$tempPath"/>
      </xsl:call-template>

      <xsl:call-template name="createBars">
        <xsl:with-param name="varNode" select="/page/workgroups/workgroup/queue/currentperiod/servicelevels/servicelevel"/>
      </xsl:call-template>

      <xsl:call-template name="createBars">
        <xsl:with-param name="varNode" select="/page/workgroups/workgroup/queue/currentperiod/abandoneds/abandoned"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </tables>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="createBars">
       <xsl:param name="varNode"/>  

       <table id="tblgraph" align="center" width="100" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
         <tr style='width:100%'>
           <td align="left" width="100%" height="10" colspan="12">
             <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" width="100%" style='color:black; font-weight:bold;'>
               <xsl:for-each select="common:node-set($varNode)">
                 <tr>
                   <td><xsl:value-of select="key"/></td>
                   <td><xsl:value-of select="value"/>..</td>
                 </tr>
               </xsl:for-each>
             </table>
           </td>
         </tr>
       </table>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

generates the following output from the XML in your question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tables xmlns:common="http://exslt.org/common">
  <table id="tblgraph" align="center" width="100" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr style="width:100%">
      <td align="left" width="100%" height="10" colspan="12">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" width="100%" style="color:black; font-weight:bold;">
          <tr>
            <td/>
            <td>..</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="tblgraph" align="center" width="100" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr style="width:100%">
      <td align="left" width="100%" height="10" colspan="12">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" width="100%" style="color:black; font-weight:bold;">
          <tr>
            <td>0..20</td>
            <td>98..</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>20..30</td>
            <td>100..</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table id="tblgraph" align="center" width="100" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr style="width:100%">
      <td align="left" width="100%" height="10" colspan="12">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" width="100%" style="color:black; font-weight:bold;">
          <tr>
            <td>0..20</td>
            <td>-..</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>20..30</td>
            <td>-..</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</tables>
```

Notes:

- Assigning the XPath expression to a variable first and then passing it as parameter does not work as can be seen in the first template call.
- I could not test the Microsoft version of `node-set()` but the `common:node-set()` function provided in `xsltproc` hopefully shows the same behavior.
- The `<tables></tables>` tag was just added to create a valid target XML file.
- The output of the `<td>` tags were simplified a little by removing the local variables.

Comment: Hi Marcus,Many thanks for your advise. I've tried this and the result is still empty. I will post an extract from the XML that is target for this code.

Comment: Could you add a `<xsl:message><xsl:copy-of select='$varNode'/></xsl:message>` debugging statement right after the `<param>` tag of your template and check if the node set is actually passed to the template?

Comment: Hi Marcus, the output is:0..20 - 20..30 - 30..40 - 40..50 - 50..60 - 60..70 - 70+ -
This should be a list where the xx..yy and the - are separated outputs

Comment: Could you try to use `/page/workgroups/workgroup/queue/currentshift/servicelevels/servicelevel` directly in the `<with-param>` tag without assigning it to a variable first?

Comment: I've done that and the result now is blank, of I however put the <xsl:copy-of select='$varNode'/> directly on the ... add here the contents of the !inner! loop then I have the full string again!

Comment: OK. I think you should include the relevant portions of your XML into your question so that I can help you debug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63491/discussion-between-marcus-rickert-and-niteowls).